# FBSDK LikeView not showing "You and xx others like this" with respect to the device Locale in Android

Tags: android, facebook-like, locale, facebook-android-sdk

I have integrated Facebook LikeView in my application which is currently live on Play store in 6 different languages.

"Like" and "Liked" button text is showing with respect to current device locale but the message "You and xx others like this" is not showing with respect to device locale.

Here is my implementation:

```
 likeView = (LikeView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.like_view);
 likeView.setFragment(this);
 likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.STANDARD);
 likeView.setHorizontalAlignment(LikeView.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
 likeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);
 likeView.setOnErrorListener(new LikeView.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    });
 likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
            PAGE_URL,
            LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in Advance.